# Nested for loop is hanging

Tags: node.js, express

I have a project that needs to pull IDs off of relationships. I first grab the tickets in an array and then loop through them to find the IDs of the timelogs attached to them. I have no problems getting the code to work, except up to this point. When it goes to get the timelog IDs off of each ticket, it will just hang here. I never get my "done" message in the console.

### Ticket Body

```json
{"id":164563,"subject":"License Upgrade","readonly":false,"messageCount":4,"previewText":"...","originalRecipient":null,"responseTimeMins":39,"resolutionTimeMins":540,"imagesHidden":false,"isRead":true,"spam":{"reports":null,"isSpam":false,"score":0,"reasons":null},"spam_score":0,"spam_rules":null,"customer":{"id":459947,"type":"customers"},"contact":{"id":459351,"type":"contacts"},"inbox":{"id":619,"type":"inboxes"},"agent":{"id":498221,"type":"users"},"status":{"id":5,"type":"ticketstatuses"},"priority":{"id":1585,"type":"ticketpriorities"},"source":{"id":1,"type":"ticketsources"},"type":{"id":2549,"type":"tickettypes"},"createdBy":{"id":459947,"type":"customers"},"updatedBy":{"id":498221,"type":"users"},"messages":[{"id":407225,"type":"messages"},{"id":420758,"type":"messages"},{"id":420918,"type":"messages"},{"id":420923,"type":"messages"},{"id":433645,"type":"messages"},{"id":433688,"type":"messages"},{"id":434765,"type":"messages"},{"id":434822,"type":"messages"},{"id":434958,"type":"messages"},{"id":435576,"type":"messages"},{"id":435582,"type":"messages"},{"id":437807,"type":"messages"},{"id":446866,"type":"messages"},{"id":446867,"type":"messages"},{"id":446871,"type":"messages"},{"id":446872,"type":"messages"},{"id":446873,"type":"messages"}],"customfields":[{"id":66,"type":"customfields","meta":{"value":""}},{"id":67,"type":"customfields","meta":{"value":""}},{"id":60,"type":"customfields","meta":{"value":null}},{"id":68,"type":"customfields","meta":{"value":""}},{"id":64,"type":"customfields","meta":{"value":""}},{"id":65,"type":"customfields","meta":{"value":""}},{"id":63,"type":"customfields","meta":{"textValue":"None","value":170}}],"tags":[{"id":218,"type":"tags"}],"files":[{"id":70784,"type":"files"}],"timelogs":[{"id":16302,"type":"timelogs"},{"id":16486,"type":"timelogs"},{"id":16574,"type":"timelogs"}],"businesshours":{"id":6,"type":"businesshours"},"company":{"id":893,"type":"companies"},"createdAt":"2023-01-14T03:06:59Z","updatedAt":"2023-01-17T13:57:29Z","state":"active"}
```

### Code Snippet

```js
 console.log(`${tickets.length} tickets to search...`)
    for (let i = 0; i < tickets.length; i++) {
      const ticket = tickets[i];
      console.log(i + 1);
      const ticketTimeLogs = ticket.timelogs;
      console.log(`Getting ${ticketTimeLogs.length} timelogs for ticket ${ticket.id}...`)
      for (let j = 0; j < ticketTimeLogs.length; j++) {
        const ticketTimeLog = ticketTimeLogs[j];
        console.log(`Got timelog ${ticketTimeLog.id}`);
        timelogIds.push(ticketTimeLog.id);
        continue;
      }
    }
console.log("done");
```

### Output

```
Result Size: 1 | Has More Pages: false
25 tickets to search...
1
Getting 3 timelogs for ticket 164563...
Got timelog 16302
Got timelog 16486
Got timelog 16574
2
Getting 2 timelogs for ticket 164602...
Got timelog 16163
Got timelog 16272
3
Getting 1 timelogs for ticket 164621...
Got timelog 16630
4
Getting 1 timelogs for ticket 164810...
Got timelog 16629
5
Getting 1 timelogs for ticket 175606...
Got timelog 16252
6
Getting 3 timelogs for ticket 175714...
Got timelog 16246
Got timelog 16247
Got timelog 16472
7
Getting 1 timelogs for ticket 182857...
Got timelog 16274
8
Getting 1 timelogs for ticket 182971...
Got timelog 16459
9
Getting 2 timelogs for ticket 183155...
Got timelog 16409
Got timelog 16411
10
Getting 1 timelogs for ticket 183241...
Got timelog 16279
11
Getting 1 timelogs for ticket 183732...
Got timelog 16344
12
Getting 2 timelogs for ticket 184405...
Got timelog 16410
Got timelog 16460
13
Getting 1 timelogs for ticket 184406...
Got timelog 16346
14
Getting 2 timelogs for ticket 184957...
Got timelog 16484
Got timelog 16607
15
Getting 2 timelogs for ticket 185148...
Got timelog 16466
Got timelog 16594
16
Getting 1 timelogs for ticket 185191...
Got timelog 16468
17
```

Full code snippet can be found here: https://gist.github.com/jonwgeorge/3ef23f169312100e210c0298221b1a7f

Comment: both loops are using i as the counter variable, change the second loop to use a different variable 'j' as the counter

Comment: I thought of that, even with changing the variable it stops on the 46th iteration. So I changed it back to i. See edit above.

Comment: Something weird is happening here....even though you have an 'if' that checks ticket.status.id === 5 || ticket.status.id == 52, other tickets timeLogs are also being printed......check your if condition closer against 'ticket.status.id'.

It would also be helpful to the question if you pasted a 'ticket' body

Comment: I made some modifications using url parameters to only pull back tickets with status ID 5 and 52. Here's a full look at the code. https://gist.github.com/jonwgeorge/3ef23f169312100e210c0298221b1a7f

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't handling potential errors/empty objects correctly. If a ticket didn't have any timelogs it was throwing an error but I wasn't accounting for it. Adding the below `if (!ticketTimeLogs) continue;` was what I needed to proceed and get the rest.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < tickets.length; i++) {
      const ticket = tickets[i];
      console.log(i + 1);
      const ticketTimeLogs = ticket.timelogs;
      if (!ticketTimeLogs) continue;
      console.log(`Getting ${ticketTimeLogs.length} timelogs for ticket ${ticket.id}...`)
      for (let j = 0; j < ticketTimeLogs.length; j++) {
        const ticketTimeLog = ticketTimeLogs[j];
        console.log(`Got timelog ${ticketTimeLog.id}`);
        timelogIds.push(ticketTimeLog.id);
        continue;
      }
      continue;
    }
```